# why is the server in Django not running?

Tags: django, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

i have hosted static files on AWS services and configured in my Django settings but when i try to run server its showing this error`"runserver can't serve media if MEDIA_URL is within STATIC_URL."
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: runserver can't serve media if MEDIA_URL is within STATIC_URL[error here][1]`

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZLJR.png)

Comment: I think the error is pretty clear. You need to change your MEDIA_URL which does not start with `/static/` or value of `STATIC_URL`

Comment: like into what bro??...exaample plz @ruddra

Comment: @xyz_asif e.g. `/media/`